# How to specify type in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object

There are two classes:

```
class Product {
  public id;
  public name;
} 

class OrderCustomer
{

    public $DeliveryDate;
    public $PhotoBefore = 0;
    public Product[] products;

}
```

So, I attempt to specify property `products` in class `OrderCustomer` as `Product` type. It should be array of products.
How to do that in php?

Comment: How to do this in version less?

Comment: use `constructor` to assign an `array` to another class variables

Comment: PHP is a weak type languages, as most scripting languages are. So you do _not_ declare the property as an array of products, but you _assign_ an array of products as value.

Comment: I know, but  I want be ensure that $products contains the concrete structure (properties), to use IDE hints

Comment: To get IDE hints you can provide a PHPdoc annotation: `/** @var Product[] */` but it won't be enforced by the code.

Comment: Typed properties are coming to PHP in 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, PHP is not a strongly typed language and what you are looking for is not possible, at least not in the same way it is in languages like C# and Java. You can get close to that functionality by enforcing what is added to the `$products` class member by making adding values to it limited to a setter class method that only accepts variables whose type is `Product`.

To get the type hint you would need to use a Doc Prop explicitly stating that that variable is intended to hold and array products.

```
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

class OrderCustomer
{

    public $DeliveryDate;
    public $PhotoBefore = 0;

    /** @var Product[] */
    public $products = [];

    public function addToProductArray(Product $product) 
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }

}
```

Because `$products` is now `protected` make sure you also make a getter for getting its value from outside of the class (i.e. by the calling code) if you intend for it to be accessed that way.

Comment: Ditto. It's insane how much rain we've gotten. The last couple of weeks have been better tho...finally...